# SQLiteException near "." while saving image Android

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

Yes, another SQLiteException, I did search around, I swear.

Anyway I've an Android app that takes pictures and saves them to a custom folder in DCIM. When saving the picture, I get an SQLiteException near ".".

Really struggling to find the error here.

Here's the method setting up the file:

```
reader = ImageReader.newInstance(largest.width, largest.height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 2).apply {
            setOnImageAvailableListener({
                // todo 2018/02/21 -- refactor this into separate method for readability
                val pathId = "${Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()}/${Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM}/"
                val folderId = File(pathId, "G6Camera")
                if (!folderId.exists()) {
                    if (!folderId.mkdirs()) {
                        Log.e("ERR", "Failed to create album folder")
                    } else {
                        Log.d("SUCC", "Album folder created successfully")
                    }
                }

                val ts = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
                val imgFile = File(folderId, "$ts.jpg")

                val cv = ContentValues()
                cv.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "$ts.jpg")
                cv.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis())
                cv.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION, 0) // not accurate
                cv.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.CONTENT_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
                cv.put("_data", imgFile.absolutePath)
                debugLog("aah", cv.toString())
                contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, cv)
                backgroundHandler?.post(ImageSaver(it.acquireNextImage(), imgFile))
            }, backgroundHandler)
```

Edit: The error which (I think) contains the actual SQL command:

```
INSERT INTO files(bucket_id,vnd.android.cursor.dir/image,datetaken,bucket_display_name,parent,format,storage_id,mime_type,media_type,_data,title,date_added,orientation,_display_name) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

bucket_id=-1617409521 vnd.android.cursor.dir/image=image/jpeg datetaken=1521071678705 bucket_display_name=Pictures parent=6 format=14337 storage_id=65537 mime_type=image/jpeg media_type=1 _data=/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1521071678713.jpg title=20180314_235438.jpg date_added=1521071678 orientation=0 _display_name=1521071678713.jpg
```

Comment: I am also struggling here because I can't see the SQL query which caused the error.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen whoops one sec, it's in the error, I'll post it

Comment: Could you add the error stacktrace please?